# Order e-mails are not being sent

Tags: email, confirmation

My Order e-mails are not being sent from Magento.

Cron Job is working, according to Aoe_Scheduler. I use SMTP. Still, I don't get a single email in my inbox. It isn't in my spambox et cetera. All the mails pile up in the table "mage_core_email_queue". What is the problem?

Comment: You should try using the SMTPPro extension, it's free, and gives you more insight in sending mails, including a mail logging and testing tool: http://www.aschroder.com/product/smtppro-magento-smtp-email/

Comment: That gives a strange message. "Het foutbericht was: 5.7.1 : Sender address rejected: not owned by user username@domain.ext". Weird. I can't find anything on the internet related to this message. Do you know anything about that?

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The SMTP didn't work because of security settings of my hosting. I hope they will help me. For now, I'm using my other mailaddress from another hoster.